# Proof in sequent calculus without cut

Tags: logic, proof-theory, sequent-calculus

I met an exercise in Gaisi Takeuti, *Proof Theory* [**Exercise 2.7**, page 14].

How to construct a cut-free proof of$\ \forall xA(x)\rightarrow B\vdash \exists x(A(x)\rightarrow B)$, where A(a) and B are atomic and distinct.

Why A(a) and B are restricted to be atomic and distinct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have to note that :

> $(∀x β → α) ↔ ∃x(β → α)$

is *valid* only with the assumption : $x$ not free in $\alpha$.

Thus - I think - when Takeuti "specify" that :

> $A(a)$ and $B$ are *atomic* and distinct

we have to read it as meaning that they are not "schematic" formulae, but "fully indicated" ones.

I.e. $A(a)$ is (for example) $R_0^1(a_0)$, with $R_0^1$ a unary predicate letter, and thus $A(a)$ is an atomic formula with only $a$ free; thus $B$, being different from $A(a)$, has no free occurrences of $a$.

This fact is necessary for the use of $\forall$-right rule in the proof of the formula.